# Is it worth it to use policies instead of conditions everywhere (taking run time checking to compile time)?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, conditional-statements

Let's imagine there is a condition in a program:

```
void foo(bool condition)
{
    .... a lot of work....

    if (condition)
        something1;
    else
        something2;

    .... a lot of work....
}
```

if at compile time, in each call of foo() we know we need something1 or something2, we can change program to this one:

```
template <bool condition>
void foo()
{
    .... a lot of work....

    SomePolicy<condition>::do_something();

    .... a lot of work....
}

template <bool Condition>
class SomePolicy
{
public:
    static void do_something()
    {
        something1;
    }
};

template <>
class SomePolicy<false>
{
public:
    static void do_something()
    {
        something2;
    }
};
```

So taking run time checking at compile time by calling `foo<true>` or `foo<false>.` Is this worthy to do everywhere and get rid of some conditions (probably will increase pipeline performance)? Is there any disadvantage of this besides a little ugly code?

P.S. the problem is that we don't want to duplicate all `foo`s  code and call foo1 and foo2 in different places.

Comment: Will `condition` be known at compile time?

Comment: I said in question, we know it at each call of foo.

Comment: Not really but OK.   Do you know which one you will call at compile time?  Or take it this way.  Does the calling of `something1` or `something2` change depending on the program inputs?

Comment: yes, but in user input I think this can be applied too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this worthy to do everywhere and get rid of some conditions (probably will increase pipeline performance)?

No, because pipeline stalls are not a bottleneck *everywhere*. It *might* be worth to do it in a hot spot where you have measured a bottleneck caused by a long dependency chain between instructions. A single branch in middle of "a lot of work" rarely has significant effect on performance.

> Is there any disadvantage of this besides a little ugly code?

It limits the condition to be checked at compile time, instead of at run time. Programs that have variable input at run time are usually more versatile.

As you pointed out in a comment, you can indeed reduce multiple runtime checks into one, using the described policy. But generating all your (apparently big, since they do lots of work) functions twice, *everywhere* can cause the executable size to grow significantly which is an undesirable side-effect.

Also, it forces you to use a template, which forces the implementation to be in the header. If you do that all over your code, then most of your code will be implemented in headers, and that will cause massive recompilations, when the implementation is modified. Which is a problem in big projects.

Comment: "Programs that have variable input at run time are usually more versatile." Can't it be applied also in case of user input? Let's imagine user inputs a bool, and I'm passing it to my class, which uses a lot of conditions. With templates I'm checking it once, and creating my class with true or false appropriately (that class can have non-template base class + CRTP with extra redirection in base class). So all condition's will be eliminating, I'm not sure compiler optimization will do  this one. This looks a little strange, we don't know it at compile time, but anyway we don't do it at runtime

Comment: probably I'm mistaken, just can't find where. What about other reason I agree, but performance is in first place for me (all code already is template anyway)

Comment: @Curiosity Ah, fair enough, it's possible to do a run time check, and then call a function with different template argument based on that, so I suppose it does not limit you to a compile time decision. But that forces the compiler to generate both versions of the function, which differ only by the conditional check. Doing this a lot will cause your executable size to bloat.

Comment: Thank you, yes I do understand that should choose between "large executable + ugly code" vs performance.

Comment: @Curiosity Good general choice in my opinion. However, if you do have measured a bottleneck, doing this in a particular part of the code can be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I think after the compiler optimized your statements it will end up with roughly the same code. You would have to measure  your performance to get an exact answer for your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any disadvantage of this besides a little ugly code?

Your code is slightly less readable for what gain? You've moved a condition check from run-time to compile time, but did you profile your code first and determine that these checks are on the hot path?

- Will you need to write additional tests to account for your refactoring?
- With the way you've refactored, you have moved some logic away from where it's needed, and potentially allowed others to (mistakenly) use it.
- Templating in general increases compile times. If you have thousands of these checks, it may be nontrivial.

So the question is, is it worth it? Probably. In general moving computation from run-time to compile time = happy end users. But if it's at the risk of additional bugs and a larger, less readable code base for a negligable performance gain then you may want to think twice.

Comment: thank you, I just wanted to know whether users would be more happy, then I'll consider tradeoffs.

Comment: @Curiosity: Users will be happy if they can tell the software is faster :-) Otherwise you may be able to add more value elsewhere with your time.

Comment: I wasn't sure that will be faster because of optimizations.

Comment: Right, so you may want to do some timing to verify. Remember that any code you touch there is a chance to introduce a bug, and if the gain is nil, then the risk isn't worth it.